# Maven springsource repo

Tags: java, maven, maven-3

I have an issue with maven that keeps looking for springsource repos and consumes a lot of time trying to get through while the repos are unavailable :

```
[WARNING] The repository url 'http://repository.springsource.com/maven/bundles/release' is invalid - Repository 'com.springsource.repository.bundles.release' will be blacklisted.
[WARNING] The repository url 'http://repository.springsource.com/maven/bundles/external' is invalid - Repository 'com.springsource.repository.bundles.external' will be blacklisted.
```

My problem is that I don't understand why those repos are fetched as :

- I don't use any spring components
- None of the dependency arrtifacts seems to be fetched from those repos ( cheked with the dependency list from mvn site )
- The repos are not declared in any of my files

I've tried to blacklist the repos on our archiva and even in my local ~/.m2/settings.xml and even if the repos site show them as blacklisted, the error keeps up popping and consuming time.

I have the impression that this repo is fetched by the dependencies plugin as this occurs on site phase after the following log message :

```
[INFO] Generating "Dependencies" report    --- maven-project-info-reports-plugin:2.6
```

And I also have a number of following errors preceding the repo errors :

```
...
[ERROR] Artifact: xerces:xml-apis:jar:2.11.0 has no file.
[ERROR] Artifact: xerces:xmlParserAPIs:jar:2.6.2 has no file.
[ERROR] Artifact: xml-apis:xml-apis:jar:1.3.02 has no file.
[ERROR] Artifact: xom:xom:jar:1.0 has no file.
...
```

Any idea on how to find the responsible (artifact or plugin) or to get rid of those errors are warmly welcomed.

Thanks for any clues

PS : I'm using maven 3.0.4 with JDK 1.7.0_04.

Answer (score 1):

Try to run:

```
mvn help:effective-pom
```

You'll see at least the following:

```
  <repositories>
    <repository>
      <snapshots>
        <enabled>false</enabled>
      </snapshots>
      <id>central</id>
      <name>Maven Repository Switchboard</name>
      <url>http://repo1.maven.org/maven2</url>
    </repository>
  </repositories>
```

Then you'll probably also see the springsource repo.

---

You can also use the [`maven-enforcer-plugin`](http://maven.apache.org/enforcer/enforcer-rules/requireNoRepositories.html) with it's Require No Repositories rule.

```
<plugins>
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-enforcer-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.1</version>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <id>enforce-no-repositories</id>
        <goals>
          <goal>enforce</goal>
        </goals>
        <configuration>
          <rules>
            <requireNoRepositories>
              <message>Best Practice is to never define repositories in pom.xml (use a repository manager instead)</message>
            </requireNoRepositories>
          </rules>
        </configuration>
      </execution>
    </executions>
  </plugin>
</plugins>
```

It will spit out the message for any dependency it finds that has a `<repository/>` tag defined.

Comment: Hi thanks for the info, unfortunately it did not solve the issue. The help:effective-pom showed no reference to a springsource repo and I used the enforcer to check the projects and get rid of a two (internal) repos declared in a pom.xml but it did not chage the springsource fetching. Any other suggestion ? Thanks again.